# FOSUserBundle. How can I redirect on a "Remember Me" login?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I want to redirect on login (including "Remember Me"), based on certain conditions.

I've implemented a [AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface.html) service.

That works nicely for interactive login but it doesn't fire on a "Remember Me" login.

I've also tried the kernel security.interactive_login event which does fire on "Remember Me" but there appears to be no way to redirect from there.

I thought the FOSUserBundle SECURITY_IMPLICIT_LOGIN event might do it but unfortunately no. It doesn't fire on "Remember Me".

Any others options?

Thanks